# Using MATLAB with UnetStack3

Tags: matlab, unetstack

Where I can find the `UnetStack API` documentation in other programming languages except groovy? I am trying to use `MATLAB` with `UnetStack3`. I went through the blog available for the same and was able to perform the action whatever was given in that blog. I want to explore more by Sending data, receiving data, and some more activities. Where I can find the syntax for performing such activities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB permits you to run Java code directly in MATLAB scripts. [Unet contrib](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib) has documentation and some examples on how to use the Java API from MATLAB directly.

See:
https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/tree/master/unetsocket/matlab

Comment: Yeah, I have seen this article. I want to extend the example of transmitting and receiving frame by taking some msg in a variable and then transferring that msg from one instance of Matlab connected to a node(node-1 of  2-node network) and receiving that msg on the other instance of Matlab connected to another node(node-2 of 2-node network) how can i do that, or where can i found the syntax similar to "tell 31, ''hello'"

Comment: Where I will get UnetStack java API documentation?

Comment: API docs: https://unetstack.net/javadoc/3.3/

Comment: The examples "Example of transmitting a frame" and "Example of receiving a frame" show the code you'd need to transmit data from one MATLAB instance connected to the first node and receive it on another MATLAB instance connected to the second node.

Comment: I had tested some of the MATLAB APIs, may be some of the functions are not available fully or moved to other java library in newer version of `UnetStack`. May be the documentation needs to be updated.